# How do I only run function if div is showing in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, if-statement, toggle

I am using the following click function to close a contact form and toggle a class on the links on my nav bar:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#home").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideUp("slow");
        $(this).toggleClass("current");
        $("#contact").toggleClass("current");
        return false;
    });
});
</script>
```

You can see the script in action on [this page](http://nickputman.com/test/index.html).  The trouble is that I only want to toggle the class on the contact link if the contact form is open (i.e. the div is showing at the top of the page).  How would I add an if clause to the script along the lines "if #panel is open run toggleClass on #contact?

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of toggling the class, you can set and remove the class. By logic, when you click at the `a#home` link, the link should get the `current` class, and the `#contact` element should not have the `current` class any more.

```
$(this).addClass("current");
$("#contact").removeClass("current");
```

If you want to not execute the function when the form is invisible, use:

```
$("#home").click(function(){
   if(!$('#panel').is(':visible')) return;
   //Rest of code
```

Answer (score 1):

Try -

```
if ($("#panel").is(":visible")) {
  //your code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if($('#panel').is(':visible'))
  $(this).toggleClass("current");
```

Answer (score 0):

There are numerous ways of checking the visibility of an element with jQuery, but I'm not sure on which mechanisms each rely, and considering I *know* your panel specifies `display:none` this ought to help:

```
if ($("#panel").css("display") != "none") {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do a visible check e.g. `if($("#contact:visible").length > -1)`, however I have seen examples where `if($("#contact"))` were sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

As of version 1.3, [`.toggleClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) accepts a `switch` parameter to determine if a class should be added or removed.

For example, using the following code:

```
 $("#contact").toggleClass("current", $('#panel').is(':visible'));
```

The class is added to `#contact` if `#panel` is visible, and removed otherwise.